# How to fix Black digit detection in hsv?

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I am trying to detect the digits and am unable to do for digits written with black pen. My code works perfectly for digits written in other color apart from black.

Black image:

[image: Need To detect this]

Blue image:

[image: e]

Red image:

[image]

```
img = cv2.imread("blue.jpg")
image = cv2.resize(img, (660, 600))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 65, 0), (179, 255, 255))
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(mask_inv, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    roi = mask_inv[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    if h > 30 and w < 150:

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('ROIs', image)
```

Comment: Could you add the image you're trying to do detection on?

Comment: Uploaded the image!!

Comment: The issue is that black has no saturation - so its S value will be low, unlike red, green or blue ink. You'd probably be better off without the HSV step and using Otsu thresholding to separate ink from paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cases when we need to segment two contrasting unknown colors(blue or black) from a relatively consistent background color, we can use `cv2.threshold()` with OTSU or `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()`.

Since the ink color is not known beforehand, so defining a HSV range won't work for all the cases. I would prefer `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` over `OTSU` due to it's adaptive nature. Expected output can be achieved as:

```
def get_mask(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 3, 4)
```

You can tweak the parameters for different image sizes but these would work for most of them. You can read more about `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` in [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#adaptivethreshold).

### Outputs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It worked for the black and blue image, but theres this another red image(added to the question) which it doesnt work for. The vertical and horizontal lines bounding the digits were the main reason I was using hsv for.